bindDN massage error - rewrite
I am testing a configuration with the rewriteMap option.
I have an error called bindDN message when the rule is redirected.
I think that I didn't use a good regexp for the rule.
My configuration :
defaultsearchbase dc=network,dc=lan
database        meta
suffix          "dc=lan"
uri             "ldaps://192.168.50.2/dc=lan"


overlay rwm
rwm-rewriteEngine       on
rwm-rewriteMap  ldap attr2dn    "ldap://192.168.50.10/dc=lan?dn?sub"
rwm-rewriteContext      bindDN
rwm-rewriteRule "(.*)" "${attr2dn($1)}" ":@"

For this test, I wish all requests are redirected to the other server.
If I am viewing a tcp frames, the cn request add a $ in frame:
cn.$user, cn=Users,dc=local,dc=lan
And, when I view log:
res_errno: 1, res_error: <000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090A58, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v4f7c>, res_matched: <>

Thank you for your feedback.

I would like to ask the question again.
I want to test openldap redirection. But when I test a bindDN,
in the logs I see the redirection to the correct uri, but I always get the same message:

bindDN massage error

my log file :
664476b1 slap_listener_activate(8): 
664476b1 >>> slap_listener(ldap:///)
664476b1 connection_get(12): got connid=1000
664476b1 connection_read(12): checking for input on id=1000
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 55 contents:
664476b1 op tag 0x60, time 1715762865
ber_get_next
664476b1 conn=1000 op=0 do_bind
ber_scanf fmt ({imt) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (m}) ber:
664476b1 >>> dnPrettyNormal: <uid=test,ou=Users,dc=local,dc=lan>
664476b1 <<< dnPrettyNormal: <uid=test,ou=Users,dc=local,dc=lan>, <uid=test,ou=users,dc=local,dc=lan>
664476b1 do_bind: version=3 dn="uid=test,ou=Users,dc=local,dc=lan" method=128
664476b1 ==> rewrite_context_apply [depth=1] string='uid=test,ou=Users,dc=local,dc=lan'
664476b1 ==> rewrite_rule_apply rule='(.*)' string='uid=test,ou=Users,dc=local,dc=lan' [1 pass(es)]
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://server2.local.lan)
ldap_search_ext
put_filter: "uid=test,ou=Users,dc=local,dc=lan"
put_filter: default
put_simple_filter: "uid=test,ou=Users,dc=local,dc=lan"
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP server2.local.lan:389
ldap_new_socket: 13
ldap_prepare_socket: 13
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 192.168.50.10:389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 13 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect: 
connect success
ldap_open_defconn: successful
ldap_send_server_request
ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
ber_scanf fmt ({) ber:
ber_flush2: 82 bytes to sd 13
ldap_result ld 0x7fce7c002920 msgid 1
wait4msg ld 0x7fce7c002920 msgid 1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x7fce7c002920 msgid 1 all 1
** ld 0x7fce7c002920 Connections:
* host: server2.local.lan  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Wed May 15 10:47:45 2024


** ld 0x7fce7c002920 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x7fce7c002920 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x7fce7c002920 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x7fce7c002920 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x7fce7c002920 msgid 1 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x7fce7c002920 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x7fce7c002920 msgid 1 all 1
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 12 contents:
read1msg: ld 0x7fce7c002920 msgid 1 message type search-result
ber_scanf fmt ({eAA) ber:
read1msg: ld 0x7fce7c002920 0 new referrals
read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x7fce7c002920 msgid 1
request done: ld 0x7fce7c002920 msgid 1
res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched: <>
ldap_free_request (origid 1, msgid 1)
ldap_parse_result
ber_scanf fmt ({iAA) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
ldap_msgfree
ldap_free_connection 1 1
ldap_send_unbind
ber_flush2: 7 bytes to sd 13
ldap_free_connection: actually freed
664476b1 ==> rewrite_context_apply error ...
664476b1 ==> rewrite_context_apply [depth=1] res={-1,'NULL'}
664476b1 send_ldap_result: conn=1000 op=0 p=3
664476b1 send_ldap_response: msgid=1 tag=97 err=80
ber_flush2: 34 bytes to sd 12
664476b1 connection_get(12): got connid=1000
664476b1 connection_read(12): checking for input on id=1000
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 5 contents:
664476b1 op tag 0x42, time 1715762865
ber_get_next
664476b1 ber_get_next on fd 12 failed errno=0 (Success)
664476b1 conn=1000 op=1 do_unbind
664476b1 connection_close: conn=1000 sd=12
664476b1 =>ldap_back_conn_destroy: fetching conn 1000

Thank you for your feedback
